# Select duplicated data from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

**Query**

```
select * from table1
where having count(reference)>1
```

[image]

I want to select * the data which have duplicate data,any idea why my query is not working?

Below are my expect result..

[image]

Comment: Two columns both named `ID`?  Come on now...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen amended my question,thanks

Comment: @Najib Razak,You deleted your sample data.Now it shows output data only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of window function `count` to find number of rows per id and reference and then filter to get those which have count more than 1.

```
;with cte as (
    select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id, reference) cnt
    from table1 t
)
select * from cte where cnt > 1;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/JGQVTA70094)

In the above solution, I have made an assumption that name and id has one to one correspondence (which is true as per your given data). If that's not the case, add name too in the partition by clause:

```
;with cte as (
    select t.*, count(*) over (partition by name, id, reference) cnt
    from table1 t
)
select * from cte where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Here id is unique and if you use partition by id, there is no use. And I didn't downvote this.

Comment: This won't meet the requirements, because your query would pick up `abu`, whose ID appears twice.  You need to change your partition.

Comment: @Tim - Correct. Thanks for the comment

Comment: I've never seen `COUNT()` used this way before, interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I might actually approach this by using a subquery with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Name, ID, reference
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY Name, ID, reference
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.Name = t2.Name AND
       t1.ID   = t2.ID   AND
       t1.reference = t2.reference
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: may i know where is table t?

Comment: @NajibRazak Sorry, I was missing an alias.  It should be `SELECT t.* FROM cte t WHERE t.rn = 2`

Comment: Old by Gold :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this ), first i get count by partition, after that i get row with count > 1

```
select No, Name, ID, Reference 
from (select count(*) over (partition by name, ID, reference) cnt, table1.* from table1) 
where cnt>1
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way (although maybe not the best for performance) would be:

```
select * from table1 where reference in (
    select reference from table1 group by reference having count(*)>1
)
```

In a subselect you have the duplicated data, and in the outter select you have all the data for these references.